# How to get and store the Window width before initializing my Nuxt App?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I am developing a nuxt app which needs to render different components based on my window width. And also will send a request to create a session, in which one of the header parameter is device width. Here is my approach to do that:

Code in my store:

```
//index.js
export const state = () => ({
  device_width: null,
  session_data : {},
 
})

export const mutations = {
  set_device_width(state, payload) {
    return state.device_width = payload;
  },
  set_session_data(state, payload){
     return state.session_data = payload
  }
}
export const actions = {

  //server init action to initialize the app with some necessary data
  async nuxtServerInit({ commit }) {

    
    if (process.browser) {
      commit('set_device_width', window.innerWidth);
    }
      var device_type = "";
      if (this.state.device_width < 768) {
        device_type = "mobile";
      } else if (this.state.device_width > 768) {
        device_type = "desktop";
      }
      var sessionData= await axios(...//api request with 'device_type' in header//....)
      commit('set_session_data', sessionData)

}
```

then in my templates I am using computed method to get the value.

```
computed:{
  isMobile(){
    return this.$store.state.device_width<768
  }
}
```

Now when I am keeping the screen size under 768, it works just fine. But in the case of desktop mode, full screen, it is always starting as isMobile==true for a few sec. Then isMobile is becoming false and automatically the desktop component is getting loaded. But for that few second I can see the mobile UI, and mainly my session data is always getting created with "device_type: mobile". Also as the page is initially starting with mobile UI, the SEO elements of my desktop UI is not working. How can I solve this? I just need to determine the screen size and store it before the initialization of the app. I thought serverInit action was the way to do that.

Comment: Use CSS media queries instead.

Comment: Its not only about UI. I need to create a session with the type of device as header data. That's why I need to fetch the width in JS before initializing the app

Comment: You can still do all that, but still use CSS for the UI.

Comment: not tested yet. will let you know soon

Answer (score 2):

you cannot get any device info on serverside, **nuxtServerInit** executes at serverside and it has no clue about the user device, therefore you cannot use **window** object in it.

alternative would be getting the device's width in a mounted or created cycle of your layouts and committing it to the store, but these will happen after initializing your app.

Answer (score 0):

As tony said, it should be more of a CSS solution for the biggest part.

If you still want to have the device somewhere, you can use fevid solution, here is some code to make it more visual.

`/layouts/LayoutDefault.vue`

```js
<script>
import { throttle } from 'lodash-es'

const watchResize = throttle(function () {
  console.log('resized properly')
  // here you should mutate your `device_type` via a Vuex mutation/action
  // and make your axios call by preferably fetching either a const/let variable
  // or a global vuex state
}, 1000)

export default {
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', watchResize)
  },
}
</script>
```

I do recommend using `throttle`, install it with `yarn add -D lodash-es` because watching for a resize is a heavy watcher and it may trigger many times, hence make your UI sluggish.

---

PS: do not use this in a middleware, otherwise the eventListener will be plugged on each route navigation.
If you are using several layouts, it would be a good idea to unmount the watcher in a `beforeDestroy()` hook.

If you want to have more details on Nuxt's lifecycle, you can check this page: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle/#server
Here, you can see that `nuxtServerInit` is indeed only **server side** hence the name.

---

EDIT: this module looks nice for your use-case: https://github.com/nuxt-community/device-module